# How to use jq @CSV filter to generate a csv file with values from different json levels

Tags: json, csv, hierarchical-data, jq

I have a JSON file from the Spotify API that lists all the songs on a specific album. The file is organized as follows:

```
.
.name
.tracks.items
.tracks.items[]
.tracks.items[].artists
.tracks.items[].artists[].name
.tracks.items[].duration_ms
.tracks.items[].name
```

I'm using jq to create a csv with the following information: song's artist, song's title, and song's duration. I can do this using the following syntax:

```
jq -r '.tracks.items[] | [.artists[].name, .name, .duration_ms] | @csv' myfile.json
```

Output:

```
"Michael Jackson","Wanna Be Startin' Somethin'",363400
"Michael Jackson","Baby Be Mine",260666 
...
```

However, I would like to also add the value under `.name` (which represents the name of the album the songs are from) to every row of my csv file. Something that would look like this:

```
"Thriller","Michael Jackson","Wanna Be Startin' Somethin'",363400
"Thriller","Michael Jackson","Baby Be Mine",260666 
...
```

Is it possible to do this using the @csv filter? I can do it by hand by hardcoding the name of the album like this

```
jq -r '.tracks.items[] | ["Thriller", .artists[].name, .name, .duration_ms] | @csv' myfile.json
```

But I was hoping there might be a nicer way to do it.

EDIT:

Here's what the file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Thriller",
  "tracks": {
    "items": [
      {
        "artists": [
          {
            "name": "Michael Jackson"
          }
        ],
        "duration_ms": 363400,
        "name": "Wanna Be Startin' Somethin'"
      },
      {
        "artists": [
          {
            "name": "Michael Jackson"
          }
        ],
        "duration_ms": 260666,
        "name": "Baby Be Mine"
      }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW, it'd be helpful to have an actual sample of JSON input someone could use to test their answers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good point. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the "Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator" section in [`jq`'s documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

```
jq -r '
  .name as $album_name           ### <- THIS RIGHT HERE
  | .tracks.items[]
  | [$album_name, .artists[].name, .name, .duration_ms]
  | @csv
' myfile.json
```

Comment: Ah makes sense!